# Dexexpress Gallery control hover animation effect and delay?

Tags: .net, winforms, devexpress

Using Devexpress WinForms Gallery control to display a bunch of images. Configured the hover images as well and now when I hover the mouse over an image, it displays an enlarged image. I'd like to change the hover effect e.g. fade-in/out or remove the hover effect altogether. As well as configure the delay after which the hover image is shown e.g. when the mouse pointer stays hovered for set number of seconds, only then should the hover image be displayed. Is any of this doable?

Answer (score 0):

Set the static BaseGallery.AllowHoverAnimation property to False to disable hower animation. See https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsRibbonGalleryBaseGallery_AllowHoverAnimationtopic for more information.